# Problem in displaying the custom Content type of each list

Tags: content-type, sharepoint-server, custom-list

I have created several custom lists in my project and I affected to each one **a custom  content type** .

After deploying the project and exploring my SharePoint site , there is only one content type which is added to all list instances.

I'm sure that the schema.xml of each list contains its custom content type ( ID and fields ).

Am I missing something else in my Project?

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Did you enable content types on your List? Check the advanced settings of your Custom List and see if `allow management of content types` has been enabled

Comment: yes it was enabled.

Comment: I try to put each list definition in a separate feature and I put all my list instances in one feature ( this feature's dependencies are all features of my list definitons). but while deploying the projet , i'm facing another problem which is : Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Dependency feature 'Model_Feature_ListDefinition_DemandesRdv' (id: 2ac11f74-2807-4cad-8cf4-451926dcadf6) for feature 'Model_Feature_ListInstance' (id: 4d3ae379-6ca5-4019-8aaf-b0073782fdfa) is not activated at this scope.